# are NSPredicate's reserved words case sensitive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

From apple doc:
[image]

These two predicates give me same result:

Uppercased SELF:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF.userType != %@", typeStr];
```

Lowecased SELF:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self.userType != %@", typeStr];
```

Are Reserved Words case sensitive?

Comment: I guess they are case insensitive since you can use `true` or `TRUE` for example, but I have no official source

Comment: I have the same guess, but I could not find an official source either.

Comment: If you look through Apple's Predicate Programming Guide you can find places where they kind of mix-and-match, using different case in different examples, e.g. `SELF MATCHES` and then `title matches`... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the link. I am trying to find an official doc mentioning the case sensitivity of the reserved words. Seems to me like apple advertise them as uppercased but I could not find any document that says they need to be uppercased.  we are doing a code review and a question wether SELF has to be uppercased or not was raised.

Comment: From my experience (and especially my memory, which may be false), they are not case sensitive. In my own use of them, I always try to put them in uppercase, to accentuate the fact that they are reserved and have a "meaning/function", not being a part of the keypath, but that's personal habits/rules.

Comment: @Larme I always use them uppercased too because everybody use them uppercased. Just could not find a reference that says they could also be lowercased and there will be no side effect of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)
"The predicate string parser is whitespace insensitive, **case insensitive with respect to keywords**, and supports nested parenthetical expressions."